# 32Bit ODBC DSN "Server does not exist or access denied" but 64 bit ODBC OK connecting to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql, windows-server-2012-r2, odbc, sql-server-2014

Using a new SQL Server 2014

Connecting via 32bit ODBC fails giving the error  "Server does not exist or access denied"

Connecting via 64 bit ODBC is successful

What might cause this?

Comment: Did you verify that the 32bit DSN actually exists on the machine? 64bit DSNs would be configured via C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe while 32bit DSNs would be configured via C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall issue!
Disabling the firewall allowed the 32bit DSN to work